# Rank of a Vandermonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let the $m \times n$ Vandermonde matrix be $V$, where $m\geq n$. 
Let $d$ such that $n \geq d$. I want a proof that $\operatorname{rank}(V)=d$ if and only if $d$ number of the elements are distinct. 
Could you help me out? A reference such as book, paper or a website link would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $m\times n$ Vandermonde matrix formed from $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_m$ is 
$$V=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & \alpha_1 & \cdots &\alpha_1^{n-1}\\
1 & \alpha_2 & \cdots &\alpha_2^{n-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots\\
1 & \alpha_m & \cdots &\alpha_m^{n-1}\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Suppose that $\#\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_m\}=d\le n\le m$. Then, without loss of generality, we may assume that $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_d$ are distinct. Clearly, $\operatorname{rank} V \le d$. By a well-known formula, 
$$\det\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & \alpha_1 & \cdots &\alpha_1^{d-1}\\
1 & \alpha_2 & \cdots &\alpha_2^{d-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots\\
1 & \alpha_d & \cdots &\alpha_d^{d-1}\\
\end{pmatrix}=\prod_{1\le i< j\le d}(\alpha_i-\alpha_j)\ne 0.$$
Hence, $\operatorname{rank} V=d$. For proofs of said formula, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) or [that](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Vandermonde_Determinant).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Suppose $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \cdots, \alpha_d$ are distinct. In this case, I don't follow why $rank(V) \leq d$. I understood that $rank(V) \leq n \leq m$, but don't know why it should be less than or equal to $d$. Can you suggest me a reference about it?

Comment: The elements $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_d$ being distinct is insufficient to conclude that $\operatorname{rank} V\le d$. However, since $\#\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_m\}=d$, we must have $\operatorname{rank} V\le d$.